# block seacrh engines for all pages EXCEPT homepage

Tags: htaccess

I have a question. Most of my site is password protected, so it is not indexed by search engines.  In other words, they don't show up in searches - this is good. There are, however about 40 or so pages that are not password protected, so they show up in searches - this is not good.

I read an interesting bit here at "Yoast":

https://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/

which discusses using:

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

in the .htaccess file. According to Yoast, it seems to be a preferred method for blocking all pages. But, I want to block all pages and allow only just one page - my main homepage.

How can I do this? Is there additional code that I can add to the above example?

Please advise.

Regards,

Steve

Comment: Please add your code **to your question**.

Comment: Hello toscho ... what exactly does "add your code to your question" mean?  I added "Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about WordPress code, not just the .htaccess.